# WPF image source binding doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know there are a lot of answered questions in Stackoverflow but I just cannot get my code working on image source binding. I don't know what I did wrong. I know the answers is probably very trivial but as a beginner on WPF I am really stuck.

the XAML is:

```
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="75" MouseDoubleClick="Button_MouseDoubleClick"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
           Width="100" Source="{Binding ImagetoDisplay}"/>

</Grid>

</Window>
```

and the C# code is:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ImageHandler NewImage = new ImageHandler();

    public MainWindow()
    {



        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = NewImage;

        NewImage.ImageToDisplay = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Image\flower.jpg"));
    }

public class ImageHandler : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private  ImageSource imageToDisplay;
    public ImageSource ImageToDisplay
{
    get { return imageToDisplay; }
    set
    {
        if (imageToDisplay != value)
        {
            imageToDisplay = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImageToDisplay");
        }
    }
 }
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}


  }



private void Button_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    NewImage.ImageToDisplay = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Image\flower.jpg"));

}
}
}
```

Comment: Your question would be much better readable if you would care for a proper code formatting, i.e. indentation.

Comment: I know you found your answer, but you should definitely consider putting the new.image.imagetodisplay = ... before setting the datacontext. This way it won't have to reload binding source when it gets updated, since you're using two way binding (it's the default). You could then switch over to One-Way or One-Time if you don't plan on changing it again in the code behind.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did the new.image.imagetodisplay=... right after the datacontext setting is because i want to check if the binding is actually working, even without using button event. it is more of a try then actual purpose. in my application, i need to keep changing the image source according to user events. that's on purpose.

Comment: @Taugenichts Both points you are making here are wrong. First, the Binding of the Source property of an Image element is by default OneWay. Even if you made it explicitly TwoWay that would have no effect at all, since an Image element never actively changes its Source property. Second, no Binding is "reloaded" in any way when you set the property after assigning the DataContext. Bindings are established later, when the MainWindow constructor has already finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the binding expression in XAML. When you run your application in the debugger, you should see a binding error message.

Change

```
Source="{Binding ImagetoDisplay}"
```

to

```
Source="{Binding ImageToDisplay}"
```

Comment: Working! But if ImagtoDisplay doesn't exist, why Visual Studio doesn't provide any warning and it can go through compiling?

Comment: Actually there is a binding error message when you run the program in debugger. Take a look at the debugger output window.